# Generic Method Issue - referencing type T

Tags: c#, .net, servicestack

I've got a method I wish to pass an `SqlExpression` and connection string to load data for a given type.  Problem is I can't seem to nail down the syntax.  My thought is to be able to call a `static` method like:

```
OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider = ServiceStack.OrmLite.MySqlDialect.Provider;
SqlExpressionVisitor<SampleItem> ev = OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider.ExpressionVisitor<SampleItem>();
var result = SomeClass.Query<SampleItem>(ev, connectionString);
```

With a method declared in `SomeClass` as:

```
public static List<T> Query<T>(SqlExpressionVisitor<T> ev, string connectionString)
{
    IDbConnection conn = connectionString.OpenDbConnection();
    var result = conn.Select<T>(ev);
    return result;
}
```

However, the way I am calling the `Select` method gives me the syntax error:

> "Error    10  'T' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method "

I am new to generics (obviously).

Comment: Well, how is `SampleItem` defined?

Comment: Could you show your class that you use in place of T? And connectionString.OpenDbConnection(); is it extension method on string or what?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> 'T' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor

So, you need to ensure that `T` has a parameterless constructor.  That simply means applying the following generic constraint:

```
public static List<T> Query<T>(SqlExpressionVisitor<T> ev, string connectionString)
  where T : new()
{ ... }
```

Your class likely already meets the conditions, you just need to ensure that someone else can't pass in a non-constructable type.

The reason for the error is that the `Select` method you're calling adds these same constraints.  You are essentially maintaining the same requirements for your method.

Comment: Just for reference, here is language documentation for generic constraints:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx

Comment: Right the:  where R : new() solved it.   Yes, the .OpenDbConnection was an extension method and SampleItem is a simple POCO that gets bound via OrmLite to a query result.  Thanks all.